# Next Js cannot find module next

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, cpanel

I created Next Js project. I deployed it to my CPanel. And I created server.js file on directory.
I called next module as require in server.js. But When I access to my website I catch an error.

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'next';

This error message.

My server.js code

```
const { createServer } = require("http");
const { parse } = require("url");
const next = require("next");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const port = !dev ? process.env.PORT : 3000;

// Create the Express-Next App
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      console.log("pathname", pathname);
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

My package json

```
{
  "name": "projectName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "next": "10.0.6",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  }
}
```

What should i do?

Thank you.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your package.json dependency section :  "@next/env": "^12.0.7"

Answer (score -1):

I've already had problems publishing a next application other than on vercel. To fix the error I had to create a docker in order to publish the application. In case someone doesn't answer with a more viable solution, I recommend looking into using a docker.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30948241)